# Pass Datagridview row data to new form

Tags: c#, sql, forms

I have two forms. Let's say form A and form B. I want to pass datagridview row data when clicked, from A to new form B. Note, datagridview is in a UserControl in form A.

I've tried using below:

Form frm3 = new Form3();

```
        frm3.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        frm3.textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        frm3.textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

However, I get a warning. "Form does not contain definition for textbox1 and no acceptable extension method ....."

I need ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Yu need an instance of the 2nd form and you need to capture the close event. See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable declaration is wrong.

```
Form frm3 = new Form3();
```

should be

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
```

And, modify text objects in Form3 to have them public accessible.

```
//private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
//private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox5;
//private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox6;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox5;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox6;
```

The base Form class has no notion of any text boxes or any other controls because they were declared in the Form3 class, not the Form class OR they were private in Form3 not accessible publicly from other classes.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it began with a new error cannot access textbox1 etc. due to protection level. So, I changed the modifier from private to public, no more errors. But now, App is debugging but nothing shows up. No form whatsoever.

Comment: You mentioned that the datagridview is inside a user control. To access controls inside a user control you need to first get a reference to the user control, then call the user control's FindControl method to get references to the individual controls inside it.
```